# How to know if the phone has already connected to a Bluetooth device while opening the app in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am developing an app, whenever there is Bluetooth connected I need to display an icon in each page. This works fine when I use a Broadcast Receiver while the app is running or minimized. This Broadcast Receiver is not called when the app is not running or killed.

Now the problem is when I try open the app again, it should display the icon based on the Bluetooth status, but I don't know how to get the latest status when launching the app.

Is there a way to get the connected Bluetooth device info on app launch or to make the Broadcast Receiver listen even when the app is killed?

Comment: if you are connected to a device already, you could save the UUID. You should stop listening to bluetooth `onStop()` and restart the connection `onStart()`. and try to connect to that UUID. You can save this value using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Comment: how to get the UUID from the device ? when ever i call the getExtraUUID then  get null.